# sub links of webview are not open on all devices?

Tags: android, json, webview

i am receiving json string and show in Android webview using `webview.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);` json string content showing fine and its links is working correctly on my device(4.1.2)but same links not open on other some devices i tried on other which version is(4.2.2) what i am missing here?

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Webview_news.this);

                                WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_news);
                                webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                                //webview.getSettings().setPluginState(true);
                                webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                                webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                                webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                                webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);


                                webview.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                                //Toast.makeText(Webview_news.this, "content= "+content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                                webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                        view.loadUrl(url);
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }



                                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
     final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Webview_news.this);

            WebView webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_news);

            webview.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                                     if (progress == 100) {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();                                    }
                                 }
                             });
```